# Add array together and show how many times each letter is used

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to find a solution on my own for a few hours now. Have triend different ways.
I need to add all the names in a column together and find how many times each letter appears.

Heres where i'm stuck, it only takes the first name from the column and shows info about it, but i need to have them all tog

```
$text=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT test from tabletest");
//Fetch result 
$text=mysqli_fetch_assoc($text);
$my_id=$text['test'];

$text = str_replace(' ', '', $text );
$arrLetters = str_split($text['test']);
$countLetters = count($arrLetters);

$letters = [];

foreach($arrLetters as $letter){
    if(isset($letters[$letter])){
        $letters[$letter] += 1;
    } else {
        $letters[$letter] = 1;  
    }
}

foreach($letters as $letter => $total){
    echo $letter.": ".$total.": ".round(($total/$countLetters*100),2)."%\n";
}
```

Comment: _..it only takes the first name from the column ..._ You will need a loop to get all the names...`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($text)) {...`

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php ?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want to count letters or bytes? Do you want to sum it up for each row in the DB result or for each one separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count frequency of each letter in an array of strings you can do so using [`mb_str_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php) and [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

For example, I have two rows in the database:

```
foo bar
this is a test of emoji
```

Consider the following code. Here I am splitting each value inside of a loop into separate characters using `mb_str_split()` and then using another `foreach` loop and `array_count_values($arrLetters)` I calculate the frequency of each character.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT test from tabletest");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    // split the string into characters
    $arrLetters = mb_str_split($row['test']);
    $countLetters = count($arrLetters);
    // count frequence of each character and immediately display results
    foreach (array_count_values($arrLetters) as $letter => $total) {
        echo $letter.": ".$total.": ".round(($total / $countLetters * 100), 2)."%\n";
    }
    echo '--------------'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

It will produce the following output:

```
f: 1: 14.29%
o: 2: 28.57%
 : 1: 14.29%
b: 1: 14.29%
a: 1: 14.29%
r: 1: 14.29%
--------------
t: 3: 12%
h: 1: 4%
i: 3: 12%
s: 3: 12%
 : 6: 24%
a: 1: 4%
e: 2: 8%
o: 2: 8%
f: 1: 4%
m: 1: 4%
j: 1: 4%
: 1: 4%
--------------
```

If you want to get the frequency for all rows as one result, then you can just implode it all into a string and do it without a loop.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT test from tabletest");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Implode it all into a single string
$text = implode(array_column($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM), 0));

// split the string into characters
$arrLetters = mb_str_split($text);
$countLetters = count($arrLetters);
// count frequence of each character and immediately display results
foreach (array_count_values($arrLetters) as $letter => $total) {
    echo $letter.": ".$total.": ".round(($total / $countLetters * 100), 2)."%\n";
}
```

Which will give you this output:

```
f: 2: 6.25%
o: 4: 12.5%
 : 7: 21.88%
b: 1: 3.13%
a: 2: 6.25%
r: 1: 3.13%
t: 3: 9.38%
h: 1: 3.13%
i: 3: 9.38%
s: 3: 9.38%
e: 2: 6.25%
m: 1: 3.13%
j: 1: 3.13%
: 1: 3.13%
```